# Deserialize array Object using Newtonsoft Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0, json.net, deserialization

I have following json string

```
[
    {
        "itemtype": "note",
        "body": "some text"
    },
    {
        "itemtype": "list",
        "items": [
            {
                "item": "some text"
            },
            {
                "item": "some text"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemtype": "link",
        "url": "some link"
    }
]
```

Which I need to parse in C#. My string might return error codes like this (or any other unknown error codes)

```
{"Error":"You need to login before accessing data"}
```

Or it might be just an empty array (no data)

```
[]
```

Here is my code

```
public void ParseData(string inStr) {
    if (inStr.Trim() != "") {
        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inStr);
        if (result is Array) {
            foreach (JObject obj in result.objectList) {
                switch (obj.Property("itemtype").ToString()) {
                    case "list": // do something
                        break;
                    case "note": // do something
                        break;
                    case "link": // do something
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // ... read error messages
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

In above code `result` is never of type `Array`. in fact I have no way to check what is its type either (I tried typeof).

**Question**

How can I check if I have an array in string and how can I check if it has objects in it (Please note, this is not a typed array)

Comment: Try checking for `JArray`...

Comment: Post is as answer and I vote up, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` will convert your Json to a [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) rather than an `Array` - update your check to:

```
if (result is JArray)
```

Comment: I was scraching my head for about 3 hours, and couldn't see that I missed the `J`.I guess it is way passed my sleeping time.Thanks again

Comment: LOL. No worries @BobSort, we've all been there :)